# Imported VDB file does not render

Tags: import, smoke-simulation

Blender breaks smoke sim into the Noise and Data folder.
I need to import only one frame out of the .VDB sequence to a new Blender scene.

Imported .VDB from Data folder renders correctly. Imported VDB from Noise folder shows up in the viewport but does not render. VDB from the Data folder looks shit, VDB from the Noise folder looks nice, but I can't make it render (all in Cycels). Any suggestions? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure there is a density field to match the shader attribute.

Comment: Thank you! This has worked and both VDBs can now be rendered.